# How to get rid of this situation in my model class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a ActiveRecord "**Car**" model:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base

  def check_value
     puts self.load_size #if user input is an alphabet letter, I got 0.0 here
  end
  ...
end
```

There is an attribute "**load_size**" in "**Car**" model, and in the database, the "**load_size**" column is a **double** type column.

The interesting thing is, in UI, if user input **alphabet letters** (e.g. 'a') in the "**load_size**" input field, my model will automatically convert this alphabet to value 0.0

In other words, if my **CarsController.rb** do something like `Car.new({:load_size=>params[:load_size]})`, and the user input `params[:load_size]` is "**a**", in the model, I got `self.load_size` equal to **0.0**

**Regards to above, I have following two questions to ask:**

**Q1**. Is it because of my "load_size" in database is a "double" type, so in **car model**, when I access `self.load_size` rails will automatically convert **alphabet value** to **0.0** ?

**Q2**. Since I have defined a validation method in "Car" model, I would like to get the original user input value (e.g. "a") without any convert. How to get rid of this? How to get user input value, not converted 0.0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1. The value is likely converted to 0.0 at the time of input, not when you access it.

Q2. You need to change the field type to a string type to be able to store text in it.